# Circuitikz: Newline in resistor labels

Tags: circuitikz

How could I go about writing the label R1, with the resistance of 560 ohms underneath it using Circuitikz?  Ideally, I want a newline in the resistor label.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
%\draw[style=help lines] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
\draw
(0,0) node[npn,rotate=90] (darl) {} node[above] {$Q1$}
(0,-3)      node[npn,xscale=-1] (npn) {} node[left] {$Q2$}
(darl.B)    to[short,-*,i<^=\SI{37.2}{\micro\ampere}] ++(0,-0.65) node (base) {}
            to[short,i>^=\SI{5.67}{\milli\ampere}] (npn.C)

(darl.E)    to[short,-*,i=\SI{518}{\milli\ampere}] ++(1.23,0) node (zen) {}
            to[short,-*] ++(2,0) node (div) {}
            to[short,-o] ++(1.5,0)  node (out1) {}
            to[short] ++(1,0)
            to[vR,i>^=\SI{500}{\milli\ampere},l=$R_L$] ++(0,-6)
            to[short,-o] ++(-1,0) node (out2) {}
            to[short,-*] ++(-1.5,0)
            to[short,-*] ++(-4,0)
            to[short] ++(-3.5,0)
            to[V,l=\SI{18}{\volt}] ++(0,6)

(zen)       to[R,l=\SI{1.2}{\kilo\ohm},i>^=\SI{5.41}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3)
            |- (npn.E)

(0,-6)      to[zD,-*,v_>=\SI{6.2}{\volt},i^<=\SI{12.7}{\milli\ampere}] (npn.E)
(div)       to[R,-*,l=$\SI{470}{\ohm}$,i>^=\SI{12.3}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3) node (fb) {}
            to[R,l=$\SI{560}{\ohm}$,v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}] ++(0,-3)

(npn.B)     to[short] (fb)

(darl.C)    to[short,-*] ++(-1,0) node (Rbe) {}
            to[short] ++(-0.235,0)
            to[short] ++(-1.5,0)

(Rbe)       to[short,i_=\SI{5.71}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-1.5)
            to[R,l_=\SI{680}{\ohm}] ++(1.76,0)

(6.5,0)     to[short,*-o] ++(1,0) node[right] {$\SI{12.7}{\volt}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: ShuntRegulator]

Comment: This should work as always and as explained in [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671). It is just a matter of how to use `align=left` for the node that is used by `circuitikz`. A rather unpleasant way would be to use `{[every node/.append style={align=left}] to[R,l=$R_1$\\$\SI{560}{\ohm}$,v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}] ++(0,-3) }` as it also changes the alignment of `6.90 V`.

Comment: Okay, though I'm not sure how this works given that the resistor is not a node, it's to[R...].  Could you perhaps give a code sample?  Where does `align=left` go?

Comment: Have you seen the linked question? It explains in great detail what `align=left` does. It basically allows you to use ``\\`` for a line-break. Other options include the `text width` key (TikZ) or the use of a `tabular` (this would avoid other nodes using the same option). And yes, the text is indeed a node (the resistor is, too). — Of course, you can also use `varwidth`; but I’d prefer that `circuitikz` would offer better ways to change certain elements (i.e. styles) and/or allows us to use something like `l={[<option>] Text}`.

Comment: Okay, this really does seems rather excessive...  Curiously, do you know any alternative to Circuitikz?  I'm actually finding it quite frustrating at times and slow.

Comment: You can use l=\parbox{5cm}{R1\\$\SI{560}{\ohm}$}.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127112/circuitikz-place-text-above-and-below-component?rq=1 about labeling both sides.

Comment: @user968243: John provided a nice suggestion, but for multiline labelling you might also want to see [Set label name on two lines in CircuiTikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65471/13304).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can label few things by yourselves:

```
(div)       to[R,-*,l=$\SI{470}{\ohm}$,i>^=\SI{12.3}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3) node (fb) {}
            to[R,v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}] node[midway,right=1.3em,align=left] {R2\\$\SI{560}{\ohm}$} ++(0,-3)
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
%\draw[style=help lines] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);
\draw
(0,0) node[npn,rotate=90] (darl) {} node[above] {$Q1$}
(0,-3)      node[npn,xscale=-1] (npn) {} node[left] {$Q2$}
(darl.B)    to[short,-*,i<^=\SI{37.2}{\micro\ampere}] ++(0,-0.65) node (base) {}
            to[short,i>^=\SI{5.67}{\milli\ampere}] (npn.C)

(darl.E)    to[short,-*,i=\SI{518}{\milli\ampere}] ++(1.23,0) node (zen) {}
            to[short,-*] ++(2,0) node (div) {}
            to[short,-o] ++(1.5,0)  node (out1) {}
            to[short] ++(1,0)
            to[vR,i>^=\SI{500}{\milli\ampere},l=$R_L$] ++(0,-6)
            to[short,-o] ++(-1,0) node (out2) {}
            to[short,-*] ++(-1.5,0)
            to[short,-*] ++(-4,0)
            to[short] ++(-3.5,0)
            to[V,l=\SI{18}{\volt}] ++(0,6)

(zen)       to[R,l=\SI{1.2}{\kilo\ohm},i>^=\SI{5.41}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3)
            |- (npn.E)

(0,-6)      to[zD,-*,v_>=\SI{6.2}{\volt},i^<=\SI{12.7}{\milli\ampere}] (npn.E)
(div)       to[R,-*,l=$\SI{470}{\ohm}$,i>^=\SI{12.3}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3) node (fb) {}
            to[R,v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}] node[midway,right=1.3em,align=left] {R2\\$\SI{560}{\ohm}$} ++(0,-3)

(npn.B)     to[short] (fb)

(darl.C)    to[short,-*] ++(-1,0) node (Rbe) {}
            to[short] ++(-0.235,0)
            to[short] ++(-1.5,0)

(Rbe)       to[short,i_=\SI{5.71}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-1.5)
            to[R,l_=\SI{680}{\ohm}] ++(1.76,0)

(6.5,0)     to[short,*-o] ++(1,0) node[right] {$\SI{12.7}{\volt}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Definitely seems rather over-the-top the length that one must go to in order to achieve this!

Answer (score 2):

Here a node with label option `xshift=xx` `yshift=xx` is used to add the label R1. Also the 560 ohm is wrapped in `raisebox` to move up and down for alignment.

To save space I only post the line 28 that needs to be changed/appended. (The rest remains same)

```
(div) to[R,-*,l=$\SI{470}{\ohm}$,i>^=\SI{12.3}{\milli\ampere}] ++(0,-3) node   (fb) {} to[R,l=\raisebox{-1cm}{$\SI{560}{\ohm}$},v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}] 
node[label= {[xshift=1cm,yshift=1ex]above:R1}]{} ++(0,-3)
```

And this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@\circuitikzbasekey/@loriginal/.@cmd\expandafter\endcsname\csname pgfk@\circuitikzbasekey/l/.@cmd\endcsname
\ctikzset{l/.code={%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar[\pgf@circ@handleOPT{\pgf@circ@handleOPT[]}#1\pgf@stop}}
\def\pgf@circ@handleOPT[#1]#2\pgf@stop{%
  \def\pgf@circ@options{#1}%
  \ctikzset{@loriginal={#2}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\pgf@circ@drawreglabel{]}{,style/.expand once=\pgf@circ@options]}{}{}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble, you can do

```
to[R,
   l={[align=left]$R_1$\\$\SI{560}{\ohm}$},
   v_=\SI{6.90}{\volt}
  ] ++(0,-3)
```

for every node separately.

Of course, you might define something like `al/.style={align=left}` to make the stuff shorter:

```
   l={[al]$R_1$\\\$SI{…}{…}$}
```

or even `al/.style 2 args={l={[align=left]#1\\#2}}` that is to be used as

```
   al={$R_1$}{$\SI{…}{…}$}
```

in the `to` path operator options.