# Tikzpicture in tikzposter title is pulled to the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

I want to build a poster with `tikzposter` using a custom title that contains a `tikzpicture`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\settitle{
    Test

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        % \node at (0,0) () {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Test
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Lorem Ipsum}{
    \lipsum
}

\end{document}
```

This is how this renders for me:
[image: screenshot]

However, when I comment in the line `\node at (0,0) () {Test};`, for some reason, the `tikzpicture` is pulled to the right:

[image: screenshot]

Where is this horizontal distance coming from, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I think that the problem stems from the fact that you are nesting tikzpictures and you may be able to avoid it by [using boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are, perhaps unknowingly, nesting `tikzpicture`s, which one should not do. [You can avoid it by using boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\newsavebox\whatever
\savebox\whatever{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
         \node at (0,0) () {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\settitle{
    Test

\usebox\whatever

    Test
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Lorem Ipsum}{
    \lipsum
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks like I was accidentally inheriting a `minimum width` which caused this shift. Thanks!