# circuitz node connection problem

Tags: nodes, circuitikz, opamp

I'm having trouble making a 3-way node using relative coordinates. Op-amps have fractional coordinates and I find it is easier to connect to using relative coordinates, but this diagram has a disconnect where R1 isn't connecting to the node I labelled.

[image]

This is my LaTeX code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw 
    (0, 0) node[ op amp, noinv input up ] (opamp) {$A_v$}
    (opamp.+) to[ short, -*, l=$V_{in}$ ] (-2, 0.5)
    
    (opamp.out)
    to[ short, -*, l=$V_{out}$ ] ++(1, 0)
    
    (opamp.-)
    to [ short, -*, name=moo ] ++(0, -2)
    to [ R, l=$R_2$, v=$v_2$ ] ++(0, -2)
    to node[ground]{} ++(0,-1)
    
    (moo) to [ R, l=$R_1$ ] ++(3,0)
    to [ short, -*] ++(0, 1.5)
    ;
    
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

Also I'm struggling to position the V1 label to the left of the terminal, or the Vout label to the right of its terminal.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Don't name the edges like that, create new nodes and connect them. See [tikz pgf - Circuitikz place text above and below component - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127112/circuitikz-place-text-above-and-below-component) for an example

Comment: In your code, `moo` is the name of the (void) element in the `short` connection. Use `coordinate` to name points in the circuit (don't get confused: an electric "node" os not a Ti*k*Z node... I call them `poles` in `circuitikz` to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}


\ctikzset{amplifiers/fill=cyan!20, component text=center}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    \draw 
    (0,0)    node[left]{$v_i$} to[short, o-] ++(1,0)
    node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=+](OA){\texttt{$A_v$}}
    (OA.-)  -- ++(0,-1) coordinate(FB) to[R=$R_1$, v=$v_2$]                  
    ++(0,-2) node[ground]{}
    (FB) to[R=$R_2$, *-] (FB -| OA.out) -- (OA.out)
    to [short, *-o] ++(1,0) node[right]{$v_o$}
    ;
    
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\texttt{$A_v$}` ? the same result you will get with `$A_v$` ;-). Anyway, +1